# VBA Copy and Paste to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to programming and |I would like some help with the following:
I need a code that when it reads in cells(x,3)="wall" then for every next row until it "hits" another element, that it to say until cells(x+1,3)<>"", it copies the values of cells A:E of that row to another sheet if these satisfy  a specific condition. The code will somehow start like that:

```
 If Cells(x, 3) = "wall" Then
Do Until Cells(x + 1, 2) <> ""
If Cells(x + 1, 4) <> "m2" Then
......
x=x+1
Loop
```

I would like some help with the part of the code in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.  Make sure that it's looking at the correct cells for your conditions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyCells()

'Some variables to keep track of where we are on the sheets
Dim x As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select

'I used 18 rows in my test set.  You'll want to change this to fit your data.
lastRow = 18
i = 1

For x = 1 To lastRow
    'Check for the first condition
     If Cells(x, 3) = "wall" Then
        'Move to the next row
        x = x + 1
        'Check that this is a row we want to copy
        'and we haven't reached the end of our data
        Do While Cells(x, 2) = "" And x < lastRow
            'Check the second condition
            If Cells(x, 4) <> "m2" Then
                'Copy and paste to the second sheet
                Range("A" & x & ":E" & x).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Range("A" & i).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                'Increment i to keep track of where we are on the second sheet
                i = i + 1
            End If
            'Go back to checking the first sheet
            x = x + 1
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            Range("A" & x).Select
        Loop
    End If
Next x

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use all those `.select` ?It's very bad habit.